# How to include AceFEM analysis in a package

Tags: packages, acegen

I would like to wrap my AceFEM analysis in one function and include it in a Mathematica package (.wl). I have followed the instructions on how to create packages from [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html) and saved the following code as "MyPackage.wl".

```
(* AceFEM` context needs to be declared before defining my functions. *)

BeginPackage["MyPackage`",{"AceFEM`"}];

 tensionTest::usage="tensionTest[number of elements] does simple tension test and returns force vs. displacement curve.";

Begin["`Private`"];

 tensionTest[n_Integer]:=Module[{nstep,result}
  , SMTInputData[]
  ; SMTAddDomain[
        "test","OL:SEPEQ1DFHYQ1NeoHooke",{"E *"->1000.,"ν *"->0.3}
    ]
  ; SMTMesh["test","Q1",{n,n},{{{0,0},{1,0}},{{0,1},{1,1}}}]
  ; SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{ "X"==0&,1->0,2->0}]
  ; SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{ "X"==1&,1->1,2->0}]
  ; SMTAnalysis[]
  ; result={{0.,0.}}
  ; nstep=10
  ; Do[
        SMTNextStep["Δλ"->(1./nstep)]
      ; While[
            SMTConvergence[10^-8,15]
          , SMTNewtonIteration[];
        ]
      ; AppendTo[result
         , { SMTPostData["u",{1,1}]
           , Total[ SMTResidual["X"==1&] ][[1]]
           }
        ]
      , {i,1,nstep}
    ]
  ; result
 ]

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Then I call this package from the notebook saved in the same directory. The package loads, AceFEM side window opens, but when I want to use the function `tensionTest` I get this strange error. I don't know why the function from the package doesn't work, because I am quite sure its syntax is correct?

```
Get["MyPackage.wl", Path -> NotebookDirectory[]]

tensionTest[10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to add another (undocumented) context `"AceCommon"` to the list as the second argument of `BeginPackage`.

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`", {"AceFEM`", "AceCommon`"}];
```

It seems that from all AceFEM symbols used in your function only `SMTInputData` is not defined in `"AceFEM"` context. Therefore when the package is called without all other necessary contexts, the symbol `SMTInputData` doesn't have the correct definition, analysis doesn't get initialized properly and fails in an unexpected way.

```
Get["MyPackage.wl", Path -> NotebookDirectory[]]

{Context[SMTInputData], Context[SMTAddDomain]}
(* {"AceCommon`", "AceFEM`"} *)
```

With this small fix in the package your function works as expected.

```
ListPlot[
  tensionTest[10],
  AxesLabel ->{"Displacement","Force"},AxesStyle->14,ImageSize -> 400
]
```

[image: displacement-force]

Comment: Does anyone know how to run the package from the example above (with specific number of elements set in the package) using of batch file?